# Youtube geo location information, get map videos

Tags: google-maps, youtube, geolocation, google-api

From Google map, there's an option to see the videos in a specific region.

Can this information be fetched using their API (Youtube API)?

I would like to pull all the available videos from a city.

**UPDATE**

Something a bit like this: https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=43.778531,-79.387207&spn=0.406035,0.891953&t=m&z=11&lci=com.youtube.all

Is there a way to fetch this list of videos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Downloading youtube videos by lat/long**

Google does not allow downloading of their Youtube videos because of deals and negotiations with content providers of those videos.

Here is a URL with someone asking the folks at Google about downloading youtube videos and the response is that this functionality is not a part of the Google API.  With a reminder to go read the Terms of Google API terms of Service.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/7iGgt-Y2MuI

If you absolutely must get the download, ultimately they can't stop you because the browser has to download it to present it to you.  Criminalization of unauthorized thoughts that occur inside your computer are under attack in this country and is a sensitive area.  This is part of the battle front on the war on general purpose computing.  You can acquire youtube videos off the wire during transport between Youtube servers and the browser, but the corporations who want you to pay a fee, surcharge, and tax for that content will fight you by twisting Google's arm to prevent you from doing so.  The solution is to spread out the video storage services to servers in other countries, so that the difficulty of patenting certain thoughts and certain videos becomes prohibitively expensive.  These handheld devices will one day be part of our minds, I don't want to wake up one day and find my mind under totalitarian control from anyone, and I mean no-one, that includes Google or any other governmental or religious organization.

**Getting a list of Youtube URL's by Lat/Long**

Yes, Google will let you search Youtube videos by query filter lat/long in the metadata and present to you the URL (not the file):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#locationsp

And there is a radius parameter, so you might be able to get videos that have lat/longs associated with their metadata inside a certain circle.

Comment: My question might be a bit miss leading, I don't want to actually download the videos. I want to get a list of all the videos from a city.

Comment: This API functionality has not been working for a while. https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#locationsp